What is known about vector subspaces of polynomial rings closed under factors?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring.  Call a nonempty subset $F$ of $R$ a factroid if it is closed under sums and factors.  That is:

If $a,b \in F$, then $a+b \in F$, and
If $a,b \in R$ with $a\in R$ regular and $ab \in F$, then $b\in F$.

Any intersection of factroids is a factroid.  Hence, one can talk of the factroid generated by a subset $S$ of $R$. It should be the intersection of all factroids that contain $S$.  Also, if $R$ contains a field $k$, then any factroid in $R$ is a $k$-vector space.
Examples:

The only factroids in $\mathbb Z$ are $0$ and $\mathbb Z$.  This is because if $0\neq n\in F$, then $1, -1 \in F$, and every element of $\mathbb Z$ is a sum of such elements.
The factroids in $R=k[x]$ ($k$ a field, $x$ an indeterminate) other than $0$ and $R$ are of the form $\{f \in R \mid \deg f \leq n\}$ for some nonnegative integer $n$. (This can be proved by showing by induction that whenever $0\neq g \in F$, all polynomials of degree $\leq \deg g$ are in $F$.)
The ring $R=k[x,y]$ has lots of more interesting factroids.  For instance, let $f\in R$ such that $f+c$ is irreducible for all $c\in k$ (e.g. $f=x^2 + y^3$).  Then the factroid generated by $f$ is the $k$-span of $\{1,f\}$.

Note: Let $R$ be a polynomial ring in finitely many variables over a field $k$ (or any other standard-graded $k$-algebra integral domain).  Then any finitely generated factroid is also finite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space.
I want to know whether this structure has been defined anywhere before (presumably under a different name!), either in the context of polynomial rings or more generally.  I want to understand more about what constraints exist on the structure of factroids.

In case of algebra over a field this looks very close to coideals in dual coalgebra of profinite completion of the algebra.

@DenisT Can you be more specific?  In particular, what do such objects look like when $R=$ polynomial ring in one or two variables over a field?

Note that, by property 2, factroids are closed under multiplication by any unit, and therefore property 1 can be replaced with the property that $F$ is a subgroup of $R$ under addition. These facts together generalize the fact that if $R$ is a $k$-algebra then any factroid is a $k$-vectorspace.

Moreover, by property 2, any factroid of $R$ that contains a regular element contains all units of $R$. Furthermore, any prime ideal that contains no regular elements, hence any minimal prime, is a factroid.

Finally, a subset $F$ of $R$ is a factroid if and only if $F$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$ such that, for any $R$-module monomorphism $R \to R$, the kernel of the composed $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism $R \to R \to R/F$ is contained in $F$, where the map $R \to R/F$ is the canonical projection.  Not sure if this helps at all.

Something else occurred to me!  If every element of a ring $R$ is the sum of finitely many units (such as any local ring or any quotient or localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at a multiplicative subset), then $R$ is the only factroid that contains a regular element.  In particular, if such a ring is a domain, then the only factroids of $R$ are $(0)$ and $R$.

Were you able to classify all factroids of the ring $k[x,y]$?
